# Multiple Nokogiri requests at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have a controller that I am trying to grab XML files from remote sources.

Something like:

```
@artist = Nokogiri.XML(open(url).read)
```

However, I want to execute multiple of these at once getting different data. Can I use threads somehow?

Executing one by itself takes abut 400ms. So when they are executed three in a row the response is up to about 1s+.

Comment: You might want to look at Typhoeus and Hydra if you are concerned about loading URLs in parallel. They're well tested tools, rather than write your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use threads:

```
named_urls = {
  artist: 'http://foo.com/bar',
  song:   'http://foo.com/jim',
  # etc.
}
@named_xmls = {}
one_at_a_time = Mutex.new
named_urls.map do |name,url|
  Thread.new do
    doc = Nokogiri.XML(open(url).read)
    one_at_a_time.synchronize{ @named_xmls[name] = doc }
  end
end.each(&:join)

# At this point @named_xmls will be populated will all Nokogiri documents
```

*I'm not certain if writing to different keys in a shared hash requires a Mutex or not, but it doesn't hurt to be safe.*

Answer (score 4):

For a large number of urls you can not open a large number of threads because you will saturate your connection bandwidth and you will start getting connection errors. For my particular cable modem and the particular server I found that 16 threads is a good value.

I used a *Mathematica* to control and vary the number of threads of my ruby web scraping program and monitor its performance for different number of threads. This is the result:

[image: performance vs threads plot]

Instead of using `Thread.new` directly, I wrote a wrapper function that opens a new thread only if the total number of threads is less than your configured maximum:

```
def maybe_new_thread
  File.open('max_threads.cfg', 'r') { |file| @MAX_THREADS =  file.gets.to_i }
  if Thread.list.size < @MAX_THREADS
    Thread.new { yield }
  else
    yield
  end
end
```

Notice that the maximum number of desired threads is just a number stored in a file named `max_threads.cfg` and this file is read every time the function is called. This allow you to change the value of this variable as the program runs.

The general structure of the program is like this:

```
named_urls = [ 'http://example.com/bar', (... hundreds of urls ... ),'http://example.com/jim']
named_urls.each do |url|
  maybe_new_thread do
    doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))
    process_and_insert_in_database(doc)
  end
end
```

Notice that each thread is storing its result in a database so I don't need to use the Mutex class to coordinate anything between the threads.

When I insert in the database, I include a column with the precise time when each result gets inserted. This is crucial so that you can calculate the performance you are getting. Make sure you define this column with milliseconds support (I used MariaDB 5.3).

This is the code I used in *Mathematica* to control the maximum number of threads and plot the figure in real time:

```
named_urls = {
  'http://example.com/bar', (... hundreds of urls ... ),'http://example.com/jim',
}
named_urls.each do |url|
  maybe_new_thread do
    doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))
    process_and_insert_in_database(doc)
  end
end

setNumberOfThreads[n_] := Module[{},
  Put[n, "max_threads.cfg"];
  SQLExecute[conn,"DELETE FROM results"]]

operationsPerSecond := SQLExecute[conn,
  "SELECT
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results)/
     (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF((SELECT fin FROM results ORDER BY finishTime DESC LIMIT 1),
                                  (SELECT fin FROM results ORDER BY finishTime      LIMIT 1))))"][[1, 1]];
cops = {};
RunScheduledTask[AppendTo[cops, operationsPerSecond], 2];
Dynamic[ListLinePlot[cops]]
```

While it is running, once you see that the performance is stable, you can change the number of threads with `setNumberOfThreads[]` and see the effect in performance.

One final comment. Instead of using open-uri's open method directly, I use this wrapper, so that is case of errors, it retries automatically:

```
def reliable_open(uri)
  max_retry = 10
  try_counter = 1
  while try_counter < max_retry
    begin
      result = open(uri)
      return result
    rescue
      puts "Error when trying to open #{uri}"
      try_counter += 1
      sleep try_counter * 10
    end
  end
  raise "Imposible to open after #{max_retry} retries"
end
```